# facebook like social plugin not working

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-social-plugins

I am trying to use the facebook like plugin which has a like and send button.The source code of my page is as follows-

```
<html>
<body>
hello
 <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
 js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=138876406236026";
 fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-send"></div>
</body>
```

Why is it not working?

Comment: this is the code for the send button only......the actual url where u puttting code?

Comment: I didn't deploy this code on a public url..i just created a sample page on my system to check this plugins..but this is not working

Comment: ok,these work for only for w3 urls......wont work locally 
http://jsfiddle.net/zHawg/

Comment: what do you mean by w3 urls???

Comment: normal online urls.......oh.forget what i said//it wont work work on your computer...when u put it on ur website it will work

Answer (score 2):

it wont work on your local system ,you should put it in your website ,
ex: www.sample.com ,

Comment: It used to work earlier when i used it on my local system....all of a sudden it has stopped working

Comment: perhaps now the codes have changed from their side?the old  iframe ones should still work

Answer (score 0):

The facebook social buttons work locally on a computer.When you put them online on your website,they will work :)